# Box collison in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

Im trying to get a player(its a square) to collide with an array of boxes. You can watch the video [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pmdANFYHBio) to see what i'm saying. But every time, it only collides with the top of the box, not anywhere under it. I will also link all the code so you guys can see(It mostly has to do with the 'map' function).

[Here is the code](http://textuploader.com/d5obm)

Comment: StackOverflow is a wiki of problems and solutions. Unless you can ask in a way that will help other people who might have the same issue in five years, no one will help you. Ask a single question, show the related code, tell us what you tried and what doesn't work. Finally, make sure everything we need to answer you is here, not on another site.

Comment: Ok big guy. No need to downvote my post.

Comment: Usually, people come back and remove their downvotes when a question/answer gets edited correctly. And my comment wasn't meant to sound harsh, just to help you help yourself.

Comment: Ok well I guess nobody needs to know about nesting for loops and box collision, so I'll delete my post.

Comment: You are completely failing to see the point. It's not the subject that is wrong, it's the way to ask. Read http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function collide(x,y,x1,y1){
    if(x+25>=x1-25 && x-25<=x1+25 && y+25>=y1-25 && y-25<=y1+25)
        return false;
    return true;
}
```

Havent had time to test it. But it should help. Let me know how it goes. Next time, please post the code segment with the problem.